# Get file path from list recent files using Microsoft graph API

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I'm new to Microsoft graph API where I query:

> GET /me/drive/recent

[List recent files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-recent?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

But I have just one problem with the **JSON** response. The attribute: `"webDavUrl"`
returns an encoded string with the **file path**.

Example of the attribute `"webDavUrl"` with the encoded value:

```
 "webUrl": sitename/Documents/Microsoft%20Teams%20Chat%20Files/Inla%CC%88mningsuppgift%20-%20test%20test.pdf",
```

Is it possible to return a **file path** in the list of recent files without the **encoding** in Microsoft graph API or do I need to decode the string myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph API returns only encoded url and you have to decode it by yourself.

In JS it should be simple by calling `decodeURI()` function.

```
const encodedUrl = 'sitename/Documents/Microsoft%20Teams%20Chat%20Files/Inla%CC%88mningsuppgift%20-%20test%20test.pdf';

// decode complete URL
const url = decodeURI(encodedUrl);
```